# Refactor RequireJS modules (AMD) to Webpack modules (CommonJS)

Tags: javascript, webpack, gruntjs, requirejs, refactoring

I need to refactor a bunch of files that have a call like this

```
define(['module1','module2','module3' etc...], function(a, b, c etc...) {

   //bunch of code

   return Something;

});
```

to

```
var a = require('module1');
var b = require('module2');
var c = require('module3');

//bunch of code

module.exports = Something;
```

Seems like a pretty simple task, 99% of the code follow this pattern, but I just can't use regex because I can't balance the brackets with it.

I already have the files traversal figured out, on a grunt task, I just need to transform the file and write it back.

```
grunt.registerTask('refactor', '', function() {
    //traverse all files   
    grunt.file.recurse('./src/js/views', function callback(abspath, rootdir, subdir, filename) {
        var c;
        //only care about .js files
        if(filename.match(/\.js$/)){
            console.log(subdir, filename);
            c = grunt.file.read(abspath); //read file

            //modify it
            c = c + "\n/* Comment appended! */";  

            grunt.file.write(abspath, c); //write it back
        }

    });

    grunt.log.write("DONE").ok();
});
```

This is a one time job, so I'm looking for a quick-n-dirty solution, I will have to check all files manually afterward anyway, I just want to save some time.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not the tool for the job.

You should use some kind of js parser, and there are many of them.
There is phrases that related to modifying code, `code-mod` & `code-shift`.

Take a look on [that tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amd-to-commonjs-codemod).